Adding directories to the favorites list in FileDialog
I am writing a golang program using fyne for the GUI. I use FileDialog to load input files. What I would like is to read a list (one or more) directories from my configuration files and add the directories to the favorites list in the left side of the FileDialog. Is this possible?

The favourites area is not adjustable using any APIs. The list is created to reflect what the operating system provides.
You could open a feature request to suggest this addition. I’m not sure if it’s commonly supported but know we won’t be able to add it for all platforms as iOS and Android don’t have the same sort of dialog with favourites menus.
